# Kohana: Undefined index when there is not one

Tags: php, kohana, undefined-index

I'm using Kohana 3.1 and I'm getting a very strange error.  The Kohana POST handler seems to think that there's an undefined index when there is not one.

Inside of a controller class:

```
$post = $this->request->post();
var_dump(isset($post['jid'])); //true
$jid = $post['jid']; //Undefined Index error.
```

If I actually use `$post['jid']` it works fine, but it is annoying to not be able to assign it to a more convenient variable.  Anyone have any idea what would cause this?

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined index: jid
84       $jid = $post['jid'];
```

var_dump of $post:

```
array(4) { 
    ["jid"]   => string(1) "7" 
    ["topic"] => string(5) "Test1"
    ["entry"] => string(14) "CHECK ONE TWO" 
    ["enter"] => string(4) "POST" 
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($post)` and paste that in your question please.

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error is occurring? Post the error message please

Comment: @tandu Are you seeing the dump above in the same request as the error? The only thing I can think of here is that you're attempting to read `$_POST` on a GET request

Comment: You must be doing something else your not telling us or there is a bug in your PHP, because that is syntactically correct and should not produce a `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: Use `Arr::get($_POST, 'jid', $default_value)`, its a very useful array function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the problem is not as obvious as the error.  The page was 302-redirecting (no post) to itself after completing the action where the post check is done.  In fact, the initial post went through properly, but be careful about calling a method on `$this` when you mean to use another object (at least when `$this` is a controller).  It's still unclear to me why Kohana didn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

Altough I believe this is a PEBKAC, you can use `$this->request->post('jid')` as a getter for that variable.

Maybe you are just [skipping the actual POST check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201230/workaround-for-validation-and-checking-if-the-form-has-been-actually-posted/6201317#6201317)?

Comment: Thanks for knowledge about the post check.  I would upvote if not for you being a jerk.

Comment: @tandu: I don't see what exactly makes me a jerk, I consider it common sense

Comment: You say "I believe this is a PEBKAC."  Hey, we all make mistakes programming..insulting people is not helpful.

Comment: @tandu: that's not an insult, I'm really sorry if you thought of it that way. I'm just used to using the term on daily basis, it's not something I use to insult anyone