# Is it a correct approach in php?

Tags: php, kohana

first of all this is my first post in stack <3 and of course sorry for my bad English.
So i'm studying PHP and i have something like a problem in my mind:

when i write a code like:

```
if ($_POST['submit'])
{
    $total = $_POST["total"];
    $var = $_POST["var"];

function func($total, $var)
    {
     $lost = $total * $var / 100;
     $income = $total - $income;
     $result = "Income - " . $income . "<br />Lost - " . $lost;

     return $result;
    }

echo func($total, $var);
}
else
{
?>


<?php 
// HTML FORM : i write to number example total = 1000
// and var = 200 and result is 1000 - (1000/100*20)
?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="total" />
    <input type="text" name="var" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php }?>
```

there is an error:
**Notice: Undefined index: submit**
when i search in google, i found a something like solution, error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)
but i think this is not a correct solution.

Comment: Probably related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201230/workaround-for-validation-and-checking-if-the-form-has-been-actually-posted

Comment: `Arr::get($array, $key, $default)` is very useful, try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty()` and `isset()` are the tools you want in this situation

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its telling you that that `$_POST['submit']` is not set ...

Try using this instead ..

```
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
```

Comment: Also, anywhere you are using the name attribute you should also have id ... so ...

Comment: <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

Comment: Also,  the accepted way of doing this, is using array_key_exists, (not empty or isset) because of certain vulnerabilities...

Comment: What vulnerabilities?  I strongly perfer empty/isset personally -- it's less verbose, and also prevents an error in the case that the array itself is not set.

Comment: @Frank Farmer - If not set it will return FALSE, not an error as you suggest.  (hence the IF() statement) Your goal in programming should be secure, functional code, not being less verbose.

Comment: If $myvar is uninitialized, `array_key_exists('submit', $myvar)` will raise a notice error, while `isset($myvar['submit'])` will not.  Can you be specific about any "vulernabilities" or "insecurities" in using isset?